# Bases that intersect to bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $V_1,\ldots,V_n$ be subspaces of $V$.

**Question:** Are there bases $B_i$ of $V_i\;(i=1,\ldots,n)$ such that $B_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap B_{i_m}$ is a basis of $V_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap V_{i_m}$ for all $1\le m \le n,\;1\le i_1 < \ldots < i_m \le n$ ?

Remark: All vector spaces can be assumed to be finite dimensional. The case $n=2$ holds and follows from the usual proof of the dimension formula. I was also able to answer the question affirmatively for $n=3$, but I don't even know about $n=4$.

Comment: In general the anwer is "no". Did you have forget a condition on $n$? Like the number of allowed subspaces equals the dimension of $V$?

Comment: @RossMillikan your counterexample is invalid, because the author asks for existence of such basis. Take $V=V_1=V_2$, $B_1=B_2=1$. Clearly, they take the intersection of basis as an intersection of sets.

Comment: @Curufin If the dimension of the space is $\ge 2$, then there is infinitely many different subspaces.

Comment: @Curufin: If the answer is "no", can you please give an explicit example ?

Comment: @Ross: By intersection I just mean the intersection of sets as described in the question.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$ with standard basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$ let $V_1=\langle e_1, e_2\rangle$. Now I chosse $V_2=\langle e_1, e_3\rangle, V_3=\langle e_2, e_3\rangle$ and $V_4=\langle e_1+e_2, e_3\rangle$. 
The intersections projected to the $x_1-x_2$-plane correspond to the lines $x_1=0, x_2=0$ and $x_1+x_2=0$. So no matter how I choose my basis in $V_1$ (the intersections with $V_2, V_3, V_4$ being 1-dimensional) I can generate only 2 of the 3 lines.

Comment: Oh by the way, I consider the intersections $V_1\cap V_2, V_1\cap V_3$ and $V_1\cap V_4$.